# How to display the filed set on a vf page

Tags: security, permissions

I have created a field set on a custom object and I am getting all the fields from the field set to a apex class. Now I need to display the field to a Vf page as inputfield. Is it possible to display the field on Vf page directly or I need to have a map to hold and display it over VF page how can we display it please guide me the best way.

Comment: have you gone thru this reference already ? it has code samples as well. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm

Comment: Here I the page you mention they are trying to get the record not displaying the filed. I need only the field not the record related to it.

Comment: So you just need the labels/names of the fields, not the values?

Answer (score 1):

See this example.

Controller:

```
public class MerchandiseDetails {

    public Merchandise__c merch { get; set; }

    public MerchandiseDetails() {
        this.merch = getMerchandise();
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Merchandise__c.FieldSets.Dimensions.getFields();
    }

    private Merchandise__c getMerchandise() {
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM Merchandise__c LIMIT 1';
        return Database.query(query);
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MerchandiseDetails">
    <apex:form >

      <apex:pageBlock title="Product Details">
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product">
              <apex:inputField value="{!merch.Name}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Dimensions">
              <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="f">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!merch[f.fieldPath]}" 
                      required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"/>
              </apex:repeat>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Hope this is what you are expecting...